# Run batch or transaction in Cloud Firestore onCreate trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Let's imagine that, in firestore, I have a collection of vendor documents :

```
vendors : {
  vendor1: {
    id: "vendor1",
    name: "John",
    shopId: "shop1"
  },
  vendor2: {
    id: "vendor2",
    name: "Mary",
    shopId: "shop2"
  }
}
```

And a collection of shop documents :

```
shops : {
  shop1: {
    id: "shop1",
    name: "My Super shop - City A",
    vendors : {
      vendor1: {
        id: "vendor1",
        name: "John"
  },
  shop2: {
    id: "shop2",
    name: "My Super shop - City B",
    vendors : {
      vendor2: {
        id: "vendor2",
        name: "Mary"
  }
}
```

For read performances, each shop document has a copy of its vendors. I copy only vendor data that are needed in my view (mobile app), and I update vendor datas on shop documents if an onUpdate trigger is launch on vendors collection.

Today, what I do is :

```
exports.updatesOnCreateVendor = functions
  .firestore.document("vendors/{vendorId}")
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {
    const vendor = snapshot.data();

    const { shopId } = vendor;

    const shopRef = db.collection("shops").doc(shopId);

    const shopAfter = {
      vendors: {}
    };

    shopAfter.vendors[vendorId] = { ...vendor };

    const batch = db.batch();

    batch.set(shopRef, shopAfter, { merge: true });

    return batch
           .commit()
           .then(console.log)
           .catch(console.error);
  });
```

I don't want to loose this copy if the cloud function failed (and I don't want to active retries on cloud functions). (same constraint onUpdate).
After reading the documentation, I conclued that using batch or transaction will guaranty that it will retry if it hasn't succeeded after 25 tries.

So, I would like to know if it's a best practice to use batch / transaction like that on cloud function triggers ?

If I refactor this and replace the batch process by just using `shopRef.set(shopAfter, { merge: true })` and if the cloud function failed, what's happening ? 
(I think I'll lose my copy :p )

Thank you for the time passed to help me better understand Firebase :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your concern is here. There is always a chance that a function invocation could fail.  There is also a chance that it will get retried if its status doesn't make it back to Cloud Functions correctly.  If you are worried that something might fail and you don't want to lose the event that triggered the function, you really *need* to enable retries on that function, and handle those retries correctly.

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing.
I just want to know if it's too much to use batch in this situation : be sure that the on create "trigger" really write my datas even if something make the cloud function failed (timeout, network issue etc).
Like I understand the documentation, batch seems to run independently.

Is it true to think that no matter what function launch a batch, it'll continue in background to commit, even if the function end ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batch isn't going to change your situation at all here.  A batch write of one document isn't any different than a normal write of one document.  All a batch will do is ensure that all of the documents writes happen atomically, all taking effect at the exact same moment.

Comment: Say the batch creates multiple documents on a collection where you have an onCreate trigger watching. Does the batch trigger the onCreate function as many times as there were documents created or does it trigger it only once? To which cas how can you get the newly added documents ?